# What should be the maximum limit of latency in elb AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I am using ELB CloudWatch. My configuration is :

```
Metric Name : Latency
Statistic : Average
Latency >=2 for 5 consecutive period(s)
```

I am getting notifications : **Threshold Crossed: 4 datapoints were greater than or equal to the threshold (2.0)**

I want to avoid these types of email. So what changes i need to do in alarm configuration. What should be the maximum value of latency ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no "correct" value.  Set it according to the behavior you expect from your application -- the latency metric is primarily measuring how responsive the back-end servers are, not the ELB itself.  It measures how long your back-end systems are taking to begin their responses.

> Latency
>
> The time elapsed, in seconds, after the request leaves the load balancer until the headers of the response are received.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/elb-cloudwatch-metrics.html